# Ksoap2 Error after Updating Android SDK and ADT

Tags: android, sdk, adt, ksoap2

I have a problem.
When I updated Android SDK tool to version 17 and the ADT to 17 I can't use ksoap2 any more.

I start the app and get this error:

```
03-25 20:13:49.995: E/AndroidRuntime(555): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-25 20:13:49.995: E/AndroidRuntime(555): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
03-25 20:13:49.995: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  at com.alcad.pernat.praksa.SplashScreen.pridobiDanasnjo(SplashScreen.java:124)
03-25 20:13:49.995: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  at com.alcad.pernat.praksa.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:73)
03-25 20:13:49.995: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-25 20:13:49.995: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
03-25 20:13:49.995: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-25 20:13:49.995: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-25 20:13:49.995: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-25 20:13:49.995: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-25 20:13:49.995: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-25 20:13:49.995: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-25 20:13:49.995: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 20:13:49.995: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-25 20:13:49.995: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-25 20:13:49.995: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-25 20:13:49.995: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I should get String with some numbers but instead I get this error.

I was using ksoap2-2.5.4.jar and tried the new ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar.
I'm using Eclipse indigo, Ubuntu 11.04.

The code looks like this:

```
SoapObject Request =new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME); // Here I get the error
                    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                    soapEnvelope.dotNet=false;

                    String tmp=odstejDatum(datum);
                    Request.addProperty("datumod",tmp);
                    Request.addProperty("datumdo",datum);
                    Request.addProperty("tip_lme",1);
                    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                    HttpTransportSE aht=new HttpTransportSE(URL,5000);
                    soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);  
//                  

                    aht.call(SOAP_ACTION_DANASNJI,soapEnvelope);                    
                    Object response= soapEnvelope.getResponse();
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android SDK tool to version 17 and the ADT to 17 they changed lib structure [more details](http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects).

> Here is the fix:

Remove the "ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar"

from the build path.

> copy the jar file into libs folder

(if not exist create it), then remove jar file from your folder(if you have custom jar folder in your project).

[image: folder structure for adding new jar files]

it will automatically take it in the build path.then, clean your project and run.